# How to export/import categories and keep their IDs?

Tags: categories, taxonomy

Using a plugin doesn't keep the IDs of the categories and exporting/importing of the `wp_terms` and `wp_term_taxonomy` tables only works on categories without parents, it seems. The admin panel still shows there are many pages of categories, but they are all empty.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can't. ID numbers given at one site might be already used at another.

Comment: Short and sweet ;-)

Comment: If the ID is already in use it doesn't allow me to import the table. Before importing it I truncate the tables I wish to import into.

Comment: @Nadroev, you should probably explain how you are doing the import/export, but short of deleting all content from the term table before importing I don't see how it can be done